# Can $L^p$ space be imbedded in some Besov space $B_{q,2}^\sigma$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, besov-space

Let
\begin{equation}
\lVert f \rVert_{B_{q,2}^\sigma} = \lVert P_0 f \rVert_p + ( \sum_{j> 0} 2^{2 \sigma j} \lVert P_j f \rVert_p^2 )^{\frac{1}{2}}.
\end{equation}
For $\sigma \ge0$ and $p \ge 2$, by Littlewood-Paley theorem and Bernstein's inequality, we can easily get that $B_{q,2}^\sigma \subset L^p$ for some $p\ge1$.

But my question is that: as for $\sigma \ge 0$ and $1 \le p \le 2$, can we get the analogous result such like $L^p \subset B_{q,2}^\sigma$?

In fact, I wonder can the following inequality

\begin{equation}
\lVert f \rVert_{B_{\frac{6}{5},2}^{\frac{5}{6}}(\mathbb{R}^3)} \lesssim \lVert f\rVert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)} \text{ holds for some p }\ge1?
\end{equation}
(However, in my opinion it may be wrong, since any $L^p$ space will not be imbedded in any Sobolev space with positive index of regularity.)

Comment: Yes you are right, improving integrability is not sufficient to improve regularity, so it will never work if $σ > 0$.